# C# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement - UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity returning NULL for some users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am currently using a method to grab to GivenName and Surname of the current logged in user from AD.  All users accessing this site will be internal users within AD.

For some users this is working and for others it seems that the UserPrincipal is returning NULL when trying to FindByIdentity.  Is this an OU thing?  I do not specify OUs to look in, I just want it to look for the current logged in user by their login name and pull their First/Last name no matter where they are in the AD structure...

Below is the code for my method...  It takes in a param containing the current user's "User.Identity.Name"...

```
public static string GetFullName(string userIdentityName)
{            
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        using (UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userIdentityName))
        {
            return principal != null ? principal.GivenName + " " + principal.Surname : "User Not Found";
        }
    }
}
```

I also output User.Identity.Name on the page and that works for everyone so I know the param passed into the method is populated.

What is odd is I can hard-code a users identity name (that normally returns a null) and the code works even though the exact same thing is being passed through the param otherwise.  Something like:

```
public static string GetFullName(string userIdentityName)
{
    var username = "DOMAIN\\username";

    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        using (UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username))
        {
            return principal != null ? principal.GivenName + " " + principal.Surname : "User Not Found";
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get it...  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thank you!!

Comment: What if you search for just `username` (without the `domain\\` part) ??

Comment: Also, try passing the identity type to the `FindByIdentity` method: `FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userIdentityName)`

Comment: None of the above worked.  Unfortunately...

Comment: I added in impersonation in the web.config and now it is all going well.

Thank you!